# OCI8 php extension installation on windows server

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, php-5.3, oci8

I have specific problem with making OCI8 work on my server installation.

First setup:

- Win 2008 Server 32bit
- ZendServer for PHP with Apache2.2
- PHP version 5.3.14 which was without php_oci8 files
- No oracle things installed

I need to be able to connect to remote oracle database, so I find out, that OCI8 extension should be used. To make OCI8 work, I also should need at least Oracle Instant Client on server, because of certain DLL OCI8 need.

What I did?

- downloaded Oracle Instant Client from their sites ( [oracle download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) ), version 11.2.0.4.0
- unpacked into folder, I choosed Program Files/oci_11_2
- added to windows variable path the address
- restarted Win
- downloaded php_oci8 libraries from PECL ( [PECL oci8 dl site](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8) )
- put them into the ext directory set in php.ini
- added extension=php_oci8.dll into php.ini
- restarted apache

After all this I checked php_info to see, if everything is ok, however no signs of oci8.

I tried older Oracle instant client, swtiching between php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll or php_oci8_12c.dll, yet nothing helped.

I found, that due to php_info in environment section doesn't show the same values, as one that are set in windows.
From php error log I also got following:

> [30-May-2014 08:02:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

Currently, I have no idea what to do, unless trying reinstalling php(which I don't want to because of many problematics connected with that), different Oracle instant clients or differenct php_oci8 libraries. I google for some hours, tried looking on Stack, but no solution, just some tips, that didn't help. Have someone encountered and solved something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Same Issue, Following steps helped me out.

1. Download instantclient and place "C:\instantclient_11_2"
2. Set environment variable for C:\instantclient_11_2
3. Check your php version i.e. PHP Version 5.6.15
4. Form http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8 download exact version, for me its php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-nts-vc11-x86.zip, unzip it and copy
   php_oci8_11g.dll to php ext folder, for me its "C:\xampp\php\ext"
5. Un-Comment "extension=php_oci8_11g.dll" in php.ini and restart apache
6. check php_info(), oci8 should be enabled.

   Thats all.

Comment: Since it was a long time, at the time I used different approach, especially because I was limited by server settings. Therefore I cannot verify your answer in my environment, however I agree this should work, hence marked as accepted.